# Executing VBA Excel macro in R with RDCOMClient: Receiving R error 80020009

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am running into an error executing a macro - remotely using RDCOMClient in R - that displays data in an Excel cell via MsgBox.

Here is the R reprex:

```
#install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
library("RDCOMClient")

# Kill any existing Excel processes
try(system("Taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F"),silent = TRUE)

#set save location for files
setwd("C:/Users/ashto/Downloads")

workbook_path <- "C:\\Users\\ashto\\Downloads\\r test.xlsm"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
Sys.sleep(1)
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(workbook_path)

xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE

xlApp$Run("output")

# Release resources:
try(xlApp$Quit())
try(rm(xlWbk, xlApp))
try(gc())

# Kill any Excel processes
try(system("Taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F"),silent = TRUE)
```

Here is the VBA macro in Module 1, which functions perfectly when run manually in Excel:

```
Sub output()

MsgBox Sheet1.Range("output").Value

End Sub
```

Excel sheet:

[image]

Here is the R console output with corresponding error code (appears to throw error when defining xlWbk):

```
> source("C:/Users/ashto/Downloads/vba wrapper_skeleton test.R", echo=TRUE)

> #install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
> library("RDCOMClient")

> # Kill any existing Excel processes
> try(system("Taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F"),silent = TRUE)
SUCCESS: The process "EXCEL.EXE" with PID 2268 has been terminated.
[1] 0

> #set save location for files
> setwd("C:/Users/ashto/Downloads")

> workbook_path <- "C:\\Users\\ashto\\Downloads\\r test.xlsm"

> xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")

> Sys.sleep(1)

> xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(workbook_path)
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 

> xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE

> xlApp$Run("output")
Error: Exception occurred.
```